# OfficeJS Outlook add-in message body text changed event on edit

Tags: office-js

Is there a way to invoke the text-changed event on the message body in item edit mode?

Not able to find it on the Msft documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request for Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Currently the feature:body changed event, as you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Outlook doesn't have a callback for something like `bodyChanged`. See a *kind of* similar request [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19483351-provide-event-notification-when-field-changes).

Please add this as a feature request as it looks like it can be useful.